# Why textview font size is looking small on newer device like nexus P . How can i resolve this issue ?

Tags: android, android-xml

[image]
As you can see the fontsize is smaller in right image than fontsize in left side image

Comment: i am using sp and tried with dp also...

Comment: The entire image on the right is scaled smaller than is the image on the left. For example, the status bar height is smaller. Hence, you are asking us to compare images that are not equivalent.

Comment: left screenshots is of nexus 5 and right is of nexus 5x. there is no scaling of images.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a setting on android.

sp and dp revolves around that, so it might be that your newer device has a lower default setting.

On your emulator do the following.

```
go to settings --> display --> font size or display size.
```

This is nice, because if you code using sp/dp in your app, it will be able to change after what the user has as default settings.

Nothing you can do to really "resolve" it, as it is a user setting, but you can design your app so that it works with smallest and largest settings.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the android official document for typography

https://material.io/guidelines/style/typography.html#typography-typeface

Best practice to use fonts size as given by android like Title, sub title etc., which make better view for all the device sizes.